# Не работает transform.right на спрайтах созданных спавном

Tags: unity3d

Возникает проблема описанная в заголовке. При создания спрайта через "спавн" мобов пушка ведет себя неестественно. При спрайте моба который уже есть в сцене заране, конечно же нет проблем. Подскажите любой ресурс, статьи, видеоуроки, ит.д. о 2д в юнити. Понимаю что дело в том, что он смотрит на префаб, а не оригинал, но как решить проблему не знаю. Также хотел бы спросить как обьединить всех мобов под тегом и обозначить пушке "врага".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public Transform target;

void Start()
{

}



void Update () {

        transform.right = target.position - transform.position;
    }
```

Отдельный скрипт спавна на пустой обьект вешаю.

```
public GameObject mobPrefab;
public GameObject respawn;


void Start()
{






        Instantiate(mobPrefab, respawn.transform.position, respawn.transform.rotation);

    }
```

Comment: Как вы создаёте врагов? динамически или каждого по отдельности ?

Comment: @Abs3akt через Instantiate, как видите.думал через корутины создать точно также как и сейчас, но как видно - не сработает.

Comment: посмотрите  [сюда](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html)  на счёт трансформа может вы не то делаете,

Comment: вы обьекту должны сказать повернись на право а не говорить поворот на право = позицией, или я вас не правильно понял

Comment: @Abs3akt, тут все правильно. Парень подсказал один и он прав. Пушка смотрит правильно на спрайт. Проблема в том, что если спрайт создан скриптом Spawn(я код предоставил), то возникает проблема(скриншот выше), но если спрайт моба я сам перенес на сцену, то все окей, работает на ура.

Comment: Посмотрите координаты тогда, попробуйте обнулить `Rotation`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `Rotation` обнулить, не могу картинку в коментарий добавить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все было бы окей, если бы по rotation.z вращался, а по остальным нет. transform.rotation =
Quaternion.Euler(0,0, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

Comment: Если у вас есть Rigidbody на обьекте то вы можете блокировать врашение по осям которых вы хотите.

Comment: его не было. добавил, запретил по x,y и все равно он по y перемещает:D.

Comment: Посмотрите в префабе как он там настроен, он берёт из префаба данные

Comment: Также запретил по х,у в префабе. толку 0. Но если я не из спавна буду создавать спрайт, а просто перетащу, то все будет окей. На мобе стоит rb2d